# How do I get this variable to be global?

Tags: java

The problem here is that I do not know where to define the variable `wage`, before its use in the if-else block to make it a field variable, so it can be recognized and used by Eclipse.

The code just below will give me the error at the last line of code: `wage` cannot be resolved to a variable. But when I place it in another line of code just under the Scanner console line (4 lines down from the top), it comes up with errors at all lines of code with the variable `wage` beneath it and says "duplicate local variable" So I do not know where to place it to make it a field variable. Any ideas anyone?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("*** Basic Wage Calculator ***");
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.println("Enter start time in 24:00 format");
        String startTime = console.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = startTime.split(":");
        double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
        double startMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
        if (starttimeHours >= 6 && starttimeHours <= 8
                || starttimeHours >= 9 && starttimeHours <= 19) {
            double wage = 1.6;
        } else if (starttimeHours >= 9 && starttimeHours >= 10 && startMinutes >= 01) {
            double wage = 43;
        } else {
            double wage = 987;
        }
        System.out.println(wage);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you understand what a field is?

Answer (score 1):

When you write double `wage = 1.6;` you are defining a variable for the scope of the `if` statement. That means after the ending **}** of the if statement we cannot access that variable. Define the wage variable outside of the if else statements. Where you have defined **startMinutes**. Instead of assigning

```
   `double wage=1.6;`
```

Change  to

```
   `wage=1.6;`
```

Comment: yes thank you I have replied to you point of the double and double wage below. I did not know it worked like that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `wage` outside of the scope of the `if` and `else` because you are accessing it via the `System.out.println(wage)`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("*** Basic Wage Calculator ***");
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.println("Enter start time in 24:00 format");
        String startTime = console.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = startTime.split(":");
        double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
        double startMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
        double wage = 0;
        if (starttimeHours >= 6 && starttimeHours <= 8
                || starttimeHours >= 9 && starttimeHours <= 19) {
            wage = 1.6;
        } else if (starttimeHours >= 9 && starttimeHours >= 10 && startMinutes >= 01) {
            wage = 43;
        } else {
            wage = 987;
        }
        System.out.println(wage);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok great thank you for the code it works fine. I noticed you changed the code within the scope into wage, not double wage. So It must be already be a double wage (as you defined beneath minutes) and does not need to be defined as double again then? So if I call it double wage within the if block it actually does notice the variable outside of the if block then? interesting... thank you

Answer (score 0):

A variable is available/can be used in the scope (pair of `{}`) in which it is defined. In case you need to increase the scope of a variable you should move it outside the `{}` so you could do it in the following manner:

```
double wage = 0.00;   // Moved wage outside the if-scope
if (starttimeHours >= 6 && starttimeHours <= 8
            || starttimeHours >= 9 && starttimeHours <= 19) {
    wage = 1.6;
} else if (starttimeHours >= 9 && starttimeHours >= 10 && startMinutes >= 01) {
    wage = 43;
} else {
    wage = 987;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is one of scope.  There are three distinct types of scope:  **loop**, **method/block**, and **class**.  These are listed from least visible to most visible.

You can think of it kind of like a Matryoshka doll - the smallest doll is the loop visibility, and the one that encompasses them all is the class visibility.  Better illustrated, it looks something like this:

```
(Class Level
    (Method/Block Level
        (Loop Level)
     )
)
```

You can intermingle these scopes somewhat, but the same general scoping rules apply.

**How does this relate to your question?**  As I said, the issue with your variable declaration is one of scope.  Move the variable `wage` to an appropriate scope level and only instantiate it *once*.

---

**Variables in scope of a loop:**  Any variables declared in the header or the body of the loop are exclusive *only* to the loop; attempting to access them will result in compilation errors.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Double aValue = new Double(10.0);
    System.out.println(i);
}
aValue = 6; // What's this variable and why is it out here?
i = 0;  // Same as above
```

**Variables in scope of a method (or block):**  Any variables declared in the body of a method or in a block of code (if-statements included) are exclusive *only* to the block.  Loops and if-statements internal to this block can manipulate the variables, but cannot declare and instantiate their own to be seen by an upper scope level.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // args is a parameter that is also available in this scope!
    // the next two variables can be used anywhere in main
    // including the if-else and loops

    String name = "Makoto";
    Integer numPhones = new Integer(1);

    if(name.length() == 6) {
        String newWord = "Wow!"; //can't be used anywhere but here
        System.out.println(name + " " + newWord);
    } else {
        String oldWord = "bummer."; //can't be used anywhere but here
        System.out.println(name + " " + oldWord);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        String word = "hello"; // can't be used in main()
        System.out.println(word + args[i]);
    }
}
```

**Variables in scope of the entire class (commonly referred to as field variables):**  These are variables that can be used by the class, regardless of what method it's in.  The only exception to this is *static* methods; if you're referencing a static field, it **must** be done so from a **static method**.

```
public class Dummy {
    private int weight;
    private int height;
    private int age;
    private int shape;
    private String name;
    private static boolean isSmart;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public static boolean getIsSmart() {
        return isSmart;
    }
}
```